# save data from form with custom foreign key field in django

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys

I have the following Model classes:

```
class ContactPerson(models.Model):            
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Appartment(models.Model):
    contact_person = models.ForeignKey(ContactPerson)
```

**Problem:** In template file I want a user to fill contact person's name, so I overwrite contact_person field as follows:

```
class AppartmentSellForm(ModelForm):
    contact_person = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = Appartment
```

In my view function I am doing the following to save data from a form submitted:

```
def appartment_submit(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AppartmentSellForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            appartment = form.save(commit=False) # ERROR HERE
            cp = models.ContactPerson(name=form.cleaned_data['contact_person'])
            appartment.contact_person = cp
            appartment.save()
            form.save();
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/sell/')
    else:
        form = AppartmentSellForm()
    return render_to_response('sell_appartment_form.html', {'form' : form})
```

**Error message**:

```
#ValueError at /sell/sell_appartment/appartment_submit/

Cannot assign "u'blabla'": "Appartment.contact_person" must be a "ContactPerson" instance.**
```

I am using SQLite, and django version 1.1.1

**Question:** How to solve this problem?

Comment: That's a rather old version of Django, is there a reason you're not using 1.3?

Comment: Updating might, after fixing all errors and deprecation warnings you would get, ease your progress, it's really better. More on topic (with dusty Django skills), if you print the cp variable, do you get what you'd expect?

Comment: @Jasper Kennis, the code fails before cp. But, yeah, if I comment out line above it, and print it, it is what I expect. Well, I am upgrading my django version...

Comment: Hm, can you alter the values contained in form that are trying to be saved? In that case you should move the line where you define cp up, and alter forms value before you run save() on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code that you are putting in your view would be better suited to the ModelForm's validation.

Override the model form's `clean_contact_person` method and add the code there so that it a) checks that the name is valid and if so, b) sets the form field's value to the actual ContactPerson instance.

Something like: (off the top of my head)

```
class AppartmentSellForm(ModelForm):
    contact_person = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = Appartment

    def clean_contact_person(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['contact_person']
        # check the name if you need to
        try:
            # maybe check if it already exists?
            person = models.ContactPerson.objects.get(name=name)
        except ContactPerson.DoesNotExist:
            person = models.ContactPerson(name=name)
            # you probably only want to save this when the form is saved (in the view)
        return person
```

Your view will may still need to use `commit=False` (since you will need to save the ContactPerson record). You can do this using the `save_m2m` method.

There's more info about `save_m2m` in [the ModelForm documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) and information about cleaning fields in [the validation documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

I hope that helps, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following:

1. Try to `exclude` the `contact_person` field, as mentioned [in point 3 over here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form)
2. or you could just not override the field in your `ModelForm` and Django will render it as a `ModelChoiceField`, unless you actually want people to type out a name instead of having a dropdown list to choose from.

Comment: if you `exclude` it, it may not try to save the string as a `ForeignKey` did you try it? ... or you can try what @adamnfish suggested.